# Filter item(s) within ListView in JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, search, javafx

I need to know how can I filter item(s) within ListView in JavaFX as I type letter in TextField.  I tried to use FilteredList with help of different google's links but haven't got the result. To clarify, I'm posting a picture of feature I want. 
Thanks!

[This feature I want in my ListView in JavaFX application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tOXW.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by two steps: set a FilteredList to your ListView, and bind a listener to your TextField.

```
//'myListView' is your ListView, 'myTextField' is your textfield
ObservableList<String> rawData= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
FilteredList<String> filteredList= new FilteredList<>(rawData, data -> true);
myListView.setItems(filteredList);
myTextField.textProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredList.setPredicate(data -> {
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCaseSearch=newValue.toLowerCase();
            return String.valueOf(data.contains(lowerCaseSearch);
        });
    }));
```